# Xcodeにおいて、Playgroundでは動くコードがCommandLineToolプロジェクトでは正常に実行されない。

Tags: swift, xcode, https

下記のように、githubAPIにGETリクエストをするという簡単なコードを書いた。

```
import Foundation

let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/(伏字)")!
let get = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url,completionHandler: { data, response,error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    guard let data = data,
          let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
        print("data or response is nil")
        return
    }

    if response.statusCode == 200 {
        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
    } else {
        print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
    }
})

get.resume()
```

このコードをPlaygroundで実行した時は、正常に取得した値が返ってくるが、Projectを作成するときにCommandLineToolを選択していると、エラーなく実行されるが値が何も返ってこない。(getできていないとしても、何かPrintされるはずだが、「program ended with exit code: 0」と表示されるのみ。)解決策お願いします。

Xcode 13.3
macOS 12.3.1

Comment: `get.resume()`の後にコンプリーションハンドラーの終了を待つ処理を入れていないため、非同期処理が始まる前にプログラムが終了しているのだと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
それと、StoryboardはPlaygroundの間違いでした...すみません

Answer (score 0):

以下を最後の行に追加するとプログラムが終了しなくなり、非同期のものも実行が確認できます。

```swift
RunLoop.main.run()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！成功しました！